# Rails routes: redirect an entire resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, rails-routing

I know about redirecting a specific route:

```
put 'users/:user_id', to: redirect('/api/v1/users/:user_id')
```

How would I apply the redirect to all routes generated by `resources`? Looking for something like

```
resources :users, to: redirect('/api/v1')
```

I can achieve a workaround using match, but it's a bit clunky:

```
match 'users/*path', to: redirect('/api/v1/users/%{path}'), via: [:GET, :POST, :PUT, :DELETE]
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently renamed a `provider_apps` resource to `apps` using the following code, which retains the query params, unlike the solution proposed in the question:

```
# routes.rb
get 'provider_apps/:slug', status: :moved_permanently, to: redirect { |path_params, request|
    query_string = URI(request.url).query
    "/apps/#{ path_params[:slug] }#{ "?#{ query_string }" if query_string }"
  }
```

This was inspired by [the block example in Rails routing docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection). You also have `request.query_parameters` available to get a hash of the query params if that's relevant to the destination route.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try something like this:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

That'll give you

```
      api_v1_users GET       /api/v1/users(.:format)                      api/v1/users#index {:format=>:json}
                   POST      /api/v1/users(.:format)                      api/v1/users#create {:format=>:json}
   new_api_v1_user GET       /api/v1/users/new(.:format)                  api/v1/users#new {:format=>:json}
  edit_api_v1_user GET       /api/v1/users/:id/edit(.:format)             api/v1/users#edit {:format=>:json}
       api_v1_user GET       /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                  api/v1/users#show {:format=>:json}
                   PATCH     /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                  api/v1/users#update {:format=>:json}
                   PUT       /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                  api/v1/users#update {:format=>:json}
                   DELETE    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                  api/v1/users#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

Edit:

```
namespace :api, path: nil, defaults: { format: :json } do
  namespace :v1, path: nil do
    resources :users
  end
end
```

That'll give you

```
           api_v1_users GET       /users(.:format)                             api/v1/users#index {:format=>:json}
                        POST      /users(.:format)                             api/v1/users#create {:format=>:json}
        new_api_v1_user GET       /users/new(.:format)                         api/v1/users#new {:format=>:json}
       edit_api_v1_user GET       /users/:id/edit(.:format)                    api/v1/users#edit {:format=>:json}
            api_v1_user GET       /users/:id(.:format)                         api/v1/users#show {:format=>:json}
                        PATCH     /users/:id(.:format)                         api/v1/users#update {:format=>:json}
                        PUT       /users/:id(.:format)                         api/v1/users#update {:format=>:json}
                        DELETE    /users/:id(.:format)                         api/v1/users#destroy {:format=>:json}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do need the non-prefixed routes (`/users`) to be functional owing to legacy clients. They just need to redirect.